# How to find out what takes so long between AJAX request and response?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss7.x

I have a simple `<p:commandButton>` that shows a `<p:lightBox>` by attribute `oncomplete`. This takes about 2.5 seconds. In a quite similar setup it only takes 51 ms.
Is there a way to find out what happens (and takes so long) between request and response?

I did not add specific code because at the moment I do not want a solution for that specific problem but rather learn to inspect and debug such problems myself.

Comment: look up some profilers?

Comment: Please add your xhtml and java code to be more clear.